# Ignoring Server Down Error Message when using Yii CMemCache

Tags: php, yii, memcached, yii-components

I've enabling yii memcached, How do I ignoring this error when dedicated memcached server was down.

> MemcachePool::get(): Server 192.168.1.200 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed
>   with: No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. (10061)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. extend [CMemCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMemCache) as your own caching component
2. override the getters and setters to return false if no connection is
   present or connection isn't active, otherwise call the parent:: equivalent method (with any necessary parameters passed)
3. configure the application component cache to use your newly extended
   version of CMemCache

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll try it and mark it as answer if success. FYI, I'm newbie in Object-oriented php.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to write more of a tutorial. It is a shame this functionality doesn't exist in the current caching application component cache as far as I know. If you're new to all that comes with php 5.3+, you may want to check out a book to keep around as a reference like http://www.amazon.com/Programming-PHP-Kevin-Tatroe/dp/1449392776/